# AWS route53 naked domain A record

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

Route53 appears to be treating my naked domain differently from `www`.

I configured route53 to point my domains, `example.com` and `www.example.com` via A record aliases to my cloudfront distribution.

The cloudfront distribution and `www.example.com` display my website, but `example.com` does not. How can this be?

In route53, I see 2 normal A records:

```
www.example.com A 123.cloudfront.net
example.com A 123.cloudfront.net
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that AWS takes a much longer time to register naked domains. Waiting solved the problem.